# ASCII string to binary vector in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, binary

How do I convert a string in MATLAB to a binary vector of the ASCII representation of that string?

For example, I want to convert

```
string = 'Mary had a little lamb';
```

to a vector looking like:

```
[0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1, etc.]
\-------v------/ \-------v------/
        M                a
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you want the entries of the array to be numbers not characters? If yes, then this should work:

```
s = 'Mary had a little lamb';
a = dec2bin(s,8)';
a = a(:)'-'0'
```

Sample output showing what this does is:

```
>> s = 'Ma';          
>> a = dec2bin(s,8)'; 
>> class(a)
ans =
char
>> a = a(:)'-'0'      
a =
  Columns 1 through 13
     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
  Columns 14 through 16
     0     0     1
>> class(a)
ans =
double
```

Comment: That would create a vector with the letters represented as their number in the alphabet, right? (Which is not what I want).

Comment: @bjarkef No, this creates a vector with doubles that are either 0 or 1. I have edited my response to show the output. The other answer creates a vector with chars, i.e. a string.

Comment: Great, looks exactly like what I am looking for then. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's quite easy, but you have to know that MATLAB internally stores a string in ASCII and is able to compute with the corresponding numerical values.

So we first convert every character (number) to binary expansion (of length 8) and finally we concatenate all these cells together to your desired result.

```
x = arrayfun(@(x)(dec2bin(x,8)), string, 'UniformOutput', false)
x = [x{:}]
```

**edit:** As Oli Charlesworth mentions it below, the same can be done by following code:

```
reshape(dec2bin(str, 8)', 1, [])
```

Comment: Can't you just do `reshape(dec2bin(str,8)', 1, [])`?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: you can do that as well (I guess that might be a bit faster, also). I didn't know you could pass empty dimensions to `reshape`, which is why I hadn't given it any thought. So thank you for that!

Comment: @Egon: Do you have an example of the output corresponding to the example input string in my question?